# In Magento Add Subcategories Link not working

Tags: magento-1.9, php, category

When  I am going to add subcategories in magento then new subcategories field not getting here is the error after clicking on add subcategories link. [image]

Comment: help me anyone.

Comment: help me anyone its urgent

Comment: Please help me anyone